# Altium Designer 23 DRC Rule Creation: How do I set a special clearance rule for a TH Pad to SMD pad?

Tags: altium, clearance, drc, design-rules

My issue: Because of wave and selective soldering techniques, I need an 8mm clearance for an SMD pad to a TH pad that is on the opposite side of a placed TH part.

Here is the scenario to better illustrate the issue: I have a TH Power OpAmp on the top-side. I can have normal clearances (as small as 6 mil) between the OpAmp's top TH pad and any top SMD component pad, but on the bottom-side I need to have a minimum 8mm clearance between the bottom TH pad and any bottom SMD component pads.

How do I structure the rule query to accomplish this?

Comment: Clearance on what layer? Do you need soldermask clearance? solderpaste clearance? creepage clearance?

Comment: @VoltageSpike, the layers are Top and Bottom only. It is only copper to copper clearance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways this could be done.

1. Easiest way. In design rules\electrical\clearance use incomponent in a clearance rule  to set the distance between two components. You could also select two pads but this will do every pad. You can then set the clearance. Set the first objects to all the through hole pads and set the second component to all the smt components   [image: V]
2. Create a component class in the schematic for each part and then send the component classes with a PCB update, make rules by using the query builder, setting the custom query to the component classes.
3. You could do the whole component and create a component to component clearance in design rules\placment\component clearance, altium will use the 3d model to calculate the clearance.

Click test queries to check and see if the number of items match, if it's zero then something might be wrong.